# Add product to wishlist without registering gives error 404 Page not found

Tags: magento2.4

I have Magento 2.4, As a guest user, I am trying to add a product to wishlist. It correctly redirect me to Customer registration page. Upon registering, Magento send a Confirmation Email. with a link to confirm.

When clicked this link, I am redirected to a 404 page with url:
https://<My_Domain_url>//wishlist/add

I am expecting to land on my Wishlist page.